# Unusual performance of the Cases function

Tags: argument-patterns, design-patterns

Recently I was surprised by unusual performance of `Cases` function. The code

```
Cases[{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, e}}, X_ /;X[[1]]==Part[RandomSample[{1, 3}, 1],1]]
```

may return `{1, a}`, `{3, c}`, `{{1, a}, {3, c}}`, or `{}`. Try reproduce this by running

```
Table[Cases[{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, e}}, X_ /; X[[1]] == Part[RandomSample[{1, 3}, 1],1]], {q,1,200}]
```

Whereas explicit substitution of pattern like here

```
Selected = Part[RandomSample[{1, 3}, 1],1];
Cases[{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, e}}, X_ /; X[[1]] == Selected],
```

always works properly. As I understand, Mathematica has difficulties with calculation of the pattern in the body of `Cases`

Comment: "As I understand, Mathematica has difficulties with calculation of the pattern in the body of Cases".

No, it's doing exactly what you've asked of it.

Check the documentation of `Cases` to understand why.

Comment: Thank you. I'll read the documentation once more.....

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
SeedRandom[1];
Cases[{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, e}}, 
 X_ /; X[[1]] == Part[RandomSample[{1, 3}, 1], 1]]  // Trace
```

[image]

As you can see, RandomSample is called separately for every element.

On the other hand, in :

```
Cases[{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, e}}, X_ /; X[[1]] == Selected]
```

RandoSample is only called once.

Comment: It's clear. After placement of my question I understood such behavior.

Comment: But I don't know how to track the execution of Cases internally.
Should one use Sow, Reap, Echo?

Comment: I used `Trace`. In general, `Trace` gives too much information a need to be restricted using options. But in your simple case this is not necessary. I added this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, `Trace` enables to see all needed info

Answer (score 3):

The explanation stems from the `Attributes` of `Condition` (short form `/;`), which contain `HoldAll`.  The standard evaluation order is head, arg. 1, arg. 2,.... The attribute `HoldAll` means that the arguments `patt` and `test` of `patt /; test` won't be evaluated, if at all, in the standard order. Exactly when the arguments of a `HoldAll` function will be evaluated depends on the function.  The exact behavior of `Condition` is not spelled out in its documentation page, so we will give it next.

When `Condition[p, test]` is evaluated as the argument of `Cases[.., p /; test]`, it evaluates `p`; if `p` evaluates to `patt`, then we have `Cases[.., patt /; test]`.  Subsequently, `Condition[patt, test]` is processed each time an expression is tested for a match.  If the expression matches `patt`, then, and only then, is `test` evaluated. As explained in the docs, if `test` evaluates to `True`, the expression matches `patt /; test`.

Example: We can trace particular functions with `On`. Uncomment `PreIncrement` to see every evaluation of `++n`.  Note that the `Less` test is not evaluated when `k` is `x` and `n` is not incremented.

```
Clear[x];
On /@ {Cases, Condition, Less(*,PreIncrement*)};
n = 0;
list = {1, 2, x, 4};
patt := (++n; k_Integer);
Cases[list, patt /; k < ++n]
Off /@ {Cases, Condition, Less, PreIncrement};
```

> Condition::trace :  patt /; k < ++n --> k_Integer /; k < ++n. >>
> Cases::trace :  Cases[list, patt /; k < ++n] --> Cases[{1,2,x,4}, k_Integer /; k < ++n]. >>
> Less::trace :  1 < ++n --> 1 < 2. >>
> Less::trace :  1 < 2 --> True. >>
> Less::trace :  2 < ++n --> 2 < 3. >>
> Less::trace :  2 < 3 --> True. >>
> Less::trace :  4 < ++n --> 4 < 4. >>
> Less::trace :  4 < 4 --> False. >>
> Cases::trace :  Cases[{1,2,x,4}, k_Integer /; k < ++n] --> {1,2}. >>

```
(* Out[..]= {1, 2}  *)
```

Each step in the evaluation sequence (except internal function operations) may be seen with `TracePrint` (it's a little long to include in this answer, but not too long to go through step by step):

```
n = 0;
Cases[list, patt /; k < ++n] // TracePrint
```